# call function within query builder

Tags: typeorm

I have a *location* entity holding coordinates. Based on a radius I want to get all locations that are within range.

I created a function (backend code / Nestjs logic, not database) calculating the distance between two locations. If the calculated distance is smaller than or equal to the radius I want to select this location.

My current repository implementation using this distance calculation function:

```
// ...
import { distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers } from '../shared/calculations/distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers';

@EntityRepository(Location)
export class LocationsRepository extends Repository<Location> {
    public getLocations({ /* ... */ latitude, longitude, radiusInKilometers }: GetLocationsDTO): Promise<Location[]> {
        const query: SelectQueryBuilder<Location> = this.createQueryBuilder('location');

        // ....

        if(latitude && longitude && radiusInKilometers) {
             query.andWhere("distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers(location.latitude, location.longitude, :latitude, :longitude) <= :radiusInKilometers", { 
                 latitude,
                 longitude,
                 radiusInKilometers, 
            });
        }

        return query.getMany();
    }
}
```

The example shown above doesn't work. I get this error

> QueryFailedError: function distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers(double precision, double
>   precision, unknown, unknown) does not exist

When adding a `:` to the function I get this error

> Function parameter isn't supported in the parameters. Please check
>   "distance" parameter.

How would I call my backend code function `distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers` within that query? I can pass in variables but not functions?

Currently I'm using a Postgres database but it would be awesome if there is an independent solution.

Comment: basically you are trying to call a function from your `node.js` app from the database, that's never gonna work, an universal solution would be to: implement that function in the database (eg. by migrations), or more driver-agnostic solution: implement that function in your query

Comment: thanks but how would I implement that function in my query? The calculation itself is a big one (30 lines of code)

Comment: Your question is more SQL related than TypeORM itself, but assuming that you are using a basic great-circle calculus take a look at that gist https://gist.github.com/rugbyprof/80da9e813b5d35fa36a8#file-great_circle-sql

Comment: thanks for that link. I tried to translate it here https://pastebin.com/AS7y7efr and got no error. But I have to check if that calculation is correct...

Comment: Have you looked at the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net) extension for PostgreSQL? It contains functionality to determine distances between coordinates (points). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/return-all-results-within-a-30km-radius-of-a-specific-lat-long-point for some examples of how to achieve a query filtering rows within a specified distance from a supplied coordinate.

Comment: thanks for the link! But I'm aiming for an independent solution, sometimes I have to use MSSQL or other databases too :)

Answer (score -1):

OK If your were to implement the following into your code, you need to evaluate the function before passing it to the SQL string. So simply:

```
if(latitude && longitude && radiusInKilometers) {
             query.andWhere(`${distanceFromCoordinatesInKilometers(location.latitude, location.longitude, :latitude, :longitude)} <= :radiusInKilometers`, { 
                 latitude,
                 longitude,
                 radiusInKilometers, 
            });
        }
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your answer. This is a NestJs (Node with TS) project using TypeORM. What should I do in my code?

Comment: sorry but this won't work because the function doesn't know about the current latlong values coming from the database table here `location.latitude, location.longitude`